# Polar coordinates with partial differentials

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

I have the problem that $f(x,y)=g(r,\theta)$, where $x=r\cosh(\theta)$ and $y=r\sinh(\theta)$. I am trying to find $\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}$ from this by using partial derivates.

So far I have an the expression:

$$\frac{\delta g}{\delta r}=\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}(\cosh(\theta)+\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}(\sinh(\theta))$$

and another one similar for $\frac{\delta g}{\delta r}$,

Also using $x^2-y^2=r^2$ and $\theta=\operatorname{tanh}^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$, I also get get expressions for $\frac{\delta r}{\delta x},\frac{\delta r}{\delta y}, \frac{\delta \theta}{\delta x},\frac{\delta \theta}{\delta y}$.

Finally I also have an expression for:

$$\frac{\delta g}{\delta x}=\frac{\delta g}{\delta r}\cosh(\theta)+\frac{\delta g}{\delta \theta}\frac{-\sinh(\theta)}{r}$$

and again a similar one for $\frac{\delta g}{\delta y}$.

But now I am not sure how to go about going any further... to get $\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}$ could anyone shed any light! Thanks!

Comment: Do not erase the whole content of the question, especially when there is already an accepted answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. Since you already know the different partial derivatives involving the coordinates just observe that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and apply it to $g$ to obtain the partial derivative of $f$ in terms of the other coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what do you mean apply it to g? Not sure how to do this?

Comment: it means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial g}{\partial\theta}+\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}$.

Comment: How did you derive that?

Comment: This is simply standard change of variable for partial derivatives. Try it for a simple case to convince yourself. In any case, it is not clear what you have or not in the problem. My interpretation was that you were interested to express the derivative of any function in $x$ using your new coordinates letting $g(\theta,r)=f(r\cosh(\theta),r\sinh(\theta))$. Also, be careful that the notation $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ is ambiguous, since $g$ is not a function in those coordinates.

Comment: The identity that I gave you before can be obtained as thinking of $(\theta,r)$ as function of $(x,y)$, i.e. $f(x,y)=g(\theta(x,y),r(x,y))$ (you have the correct formulas), and apply then the chain rule.

Comment: I’m not sure if I’m being stupid or what, but I am still quite confused on how to use the chain rule if I don’t have $\frac{\delta g}{\delta \theta}$?

Comment: Or even $\frac{\delta g}{\delta r}$

Comment: Don't worry, just ask everything you want. What I cannot really get from your question, is the given data of the problem. Is $f$ a given function in $x,y$ or $g$ a given function in $r,\theta$? Because, in the first case you simply have to apply the classical derivative along $x$, and in the second case you can actually compute the partial derivatives of $g$ in $\theta,r$, since you already have the function in those variables. Please explain it to me, so that I can help you better :)

Comment: Thank you! The question literally says f is of x and y and G is of r and theta, and that are they equal?!

Comment: Ok, but you agree with me that one of the two must be given, if not you cannot compute any of the derivatives?

Comment: Here an example (with classical polar coordinates for simplicity): suppose $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)$. Then $f(x,y)=g(r,\theta)=r^2$. Now, clearly one can compute $\partial_xf$ in two different ways: the first is simply using $f$: $\partial_xf(x,y)=2x$, the second one is using the given $g$. In that case $\partial_xf(x,y)=\partial_xg(r(x,y),\theta(x,y))=\partial_rg(r(x,y),\theta(x,y))\partial_xr(x,y)+\partial_\theta g(r(x,y),\theta(x,y))\partial_x\theta(x,y)$ by the chain rule. Then you can express the quantity.

Comment: Of course is going to be the same but the point is that sometimes is better to work with polar, for instance suppose the function $f$ to be radial. In cartesian coordinates it would be a way messier.